# Canvas oddness in painting app

Tags: jquery, canvas, paint

I was looking at this canvas painting app as a base template but was hopeful some could help alleviate a problem when you simply click the mouse on the canvas. You appear to get a line instead of a simple dot...http://luhuiya.byethost7.com/demo/mspaint.html

Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/sxppU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing dot in mouseup event by statement draw(beginX, beginY, e.pageX , e.pageY); as given below. e.pageX-8 and e.pageY-8 is causing the rendering of line instead of point. change it to
e.pageX and e.pageY.

I have commented the previous statement and wrote new statement in the mouseup event.

```
 $("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(e) {
      // draw(beginX, beginY, e.pageX-8 , e.pageY -8);
      draw(beginX, beginY, e.pageX , e.pageY);
      isDraw = false;
  });
```

Comment: why `-2` over just removing the minus clause?

Comment: You are right it should be zero, just to make sure problem lies here and to make it more visible

Comment: Then, you should make it zero in your solution. I'd also like to see the answer formatted more properly, as currently the replace clause isn't formatted as code.